# Loading files from all directories inside specific directory

Tags: node.js, webpack, require, vuex, nuxt.js

Good time of the day,
I've been trying to add 'modularity' to my application by splitting the Vuex store into many different locations.

So far, i'm totally fine with loading 'local' modules (inside the store folder) with the following piece of code:

```
const localRequireContext = require.context('./modules', false, /.*\.js$/);

const localModules = localRequireContext.keys().map((file) => [file.replace(/(^.\/)|(\.js$)/g, ''), localRequireContext(file)]).reduce((localModules, [name, module]) => {
    if (module.namespaced === undefined) {
        module.namespaced = true;
    }
    return { ...localModules, [name]: module };
}, {});

const createStore = () => {
    return new Vuex.Store({
        modules: localModules
    })
};

export default createStore;
```

However, what i'm trying to achieve seems to be rather impossible for me (i'm not new to the web app development, but actually never had a chance to play around with 'core' libraries of Node.js, Webpack, etc).

I have the following structure

```
root
|-assets
|-components
|-config
|-lang
|-layouts
|-libs
|-middleware
|-modules
|----company
|--------module
|-----------store
|--------------index.js (module index)
|-pages
|-plugins
|-store
|----index.js (main index)
```

So what i'm trying to achieve, is to get to the `~/modules` folder, go inside each of `company` directory (namespace for module), open the `module` directory (the name of the module), navigate to the `store` folder and import `index.js` file, with roughly the following content:

```
import module from '../config/module';

export const namespace = [module.namespace, module.name].join('/');

export const state = () => ({
    quotes: null,
    team: null,
    articles: null
});

export const getters = {
    quotes: (state) => state.quotes,
    team: (state) => state.team,
    articles: (state) => state.articles
};
```

As i've already said, i'm not much of a 'guru' when it comes to these complicated (for me) things, so any help is really appreciated!

So far, i went the 'dumb road' and just tried to use the following:

```
const modulesRequireContext = require.context('../modules/**/**/store', false, /.*\.js$/);
```

But, no luck it is - ***Cannot find module 'undefined'***

The final file (in my mind) should look something like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const localRequireContext = require.context('./modules', false, /.*\.js$/);

const localModules = localRequireContext.keys().map((file) => [file.replace(/(^.\/)|(\.js$)/g, ''), localRequireContext(file)]).reduce((localModules, [name, module]) => {
    if (module.namespaced === undefined) {
        module.namespaced = true;
    }
    return { ...localModules, [name]: module };
}, {});

const modulesRequireContext = require.context('CORRECT_WAY_OF_SEARCHING_IN_SUB_DIRECTORIES', false, /.*\.js$/);

const addedModules = modulesRequireContext.keys().map((file) => [file.replace(/(^.\/)|(\.js$)/g, ''), modulesRequireContext(file)]).reduce((addedModules, [name, module]) => {
    return { ...addedModules, [module.namespace]: module };
}, {});

let modules = { ...localModules, ...addedModules };

const createStore = () => {
    return new Vuex.Store({
        modules: modules
    })
};

export default createStore;
```